# Specify connection string for a query with DbContextScope project

Tags: entity-framework, connection-string, dbcontext

I am currently using [Mehdi El Gueddari's DbContextScope project](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/), I think by the book, and it's awesome. But I came across a problem I'm unsure how to solve today. I have a query that I need to execute using a different database login/user because it requires additional permissions. I can create another connection string in my web.config, but I'm not sure how to specify that for this query, I want to use this new connection string. Here is my usage:

In my logic layer:

```
private static IDbContextScopeFactory _dbContextFactory = new DbContextScopeFactory();

public static Guid GetFacilityID(string altID)
{
            ...
            using (_dbContextFactory.CreateReadOnly())
            {
                entity = entities.GetFacilityID(altID)
            }
}
```

That calls into my data layer which would look something like this:

```
private AmbientDbContextLocator _dbcLocator = new AmbientDbContextLocator();

    protected CRMEntities DBContext
    {
        get
        {
            var dbContext = _dbcLocator.Get<CRMEntities>();

            if (dbContext == null)
                throw new InvalidOperationException("No ambient DbContext....");

            return dbContext;
        }
    }

    public virtual Guid GetFaciltyID(string altID)
    {
        return DBContext.Set<Facility>().Where(f => f.altID = altID).Select(f => f.ID).FirstOrDefault();
    }
```

Currently my connection string is set in the default way:

```
public partial class CRMEntities : DbContext
{
    public CRMEntities()
        : base("name=CRMEntities")
    {}
}
```

Is it possible for this specific query to use a different connection string and how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up modifying the source code in a way that feels slightly hacky, but is getting the job done for now. I created a new `IAmbientDbContextLocator` with a `Get<TDbContext>` method override that accepts a connection string:

```
    public TDbContext Get<TDbContext>(string nameOrConnectionString) where TDbContext : DbContext
    {
        var ambientDbContextScope = DbContextScope.GetAmbientScope();
        return ambientDbContextScope == null ? null : ambientDbContextScope.DbContexts.Get<TDbContext>(nameOrConnectionString);
    }
```

Then I updated the `DbContextCollection` to pass this parameter to the `DbContext`'s existing constructor overload. Last, I updated the `DbContextCollection`  maintain a `Dictionary<KeyValuePair<Type, string>, DbContext>` instead of a `Dictionary<Type, DbContext>` as its cached `_initializedDbContexts` where the added `string` is the `nameOrConnectionString` param. So in other words, I updated it to cache unique `DbContext` type/connection string pairs.

Then I can get at the `DbContext` with the connection I need like this:

```
var dbContext = new CustomAmbientDbContextLocator().Get<CRMEntities>("name=CRMEntitiesAdmin");
```

Of course you'd have to be careful your code doesn't end up going through two different contexts/connection strings when it should be going through the same one. In my case I have them separated into two different data access class implementations.

Comment: I think this is about the way to do it. You could add a safeguard that contexts are only added to the dictionary if their `Database` has the same connection string as the previous item (if present).